# Changing the gravity pull on specific nodes with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, gravity

I'm trying to make a game where nodes fall from the top of the screen to the bottom, which I've done by using gravity. Now I want to move some nodes from the left side to the right.

I was wondering if I could change the gravity pull on different nodes instead of them falling down the screen the gravity could pull selected nodes left to right.

I know I can do this by using a NSTimer and a function but wondering if I could do this with gravity.

I have tried googling the answer but I can't find the answer to applying two gravity pulls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have 2 distinct gravity forces into the same physics world.

However if you want some node to "fall" to right you could

1. Apply another acceleration (same as gravity but opposite direction) to that specific body (this will cancel the gravity pull)
2. Apply one more acceleration versus right to the specific node.